# Stub a function which exports a method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I am using a module called adm-zip and this is how I am adding it into my file.

```
const AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
let zip = new AdmZip(filePath);
const response = await zip.extractAllTo(outputPath, true);
```

Now I am writing unit test cases and I am trying to stub AdmZip because, as shown [here](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/blob/master/adm-zip.js), it exports a function and when called with new it returns an object which has the method I want to stub.

I tried doing `sinon.stub(AdmZip.prototype, 'extractAllTo').returns('test');`  but it throws error saying `extractAllTo` property doesn't exists.

How do I stub **AdmZip** and its method **extractAllTo**?

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code you have shown consists solely of interactions with adm-zip.  Therefore, what kind of bugs do you want to find with unit-testing?

The only kind of bugs one would expect here are bugs in the use of adm-zip: Calling the wrong constructor, passing wrong arguments etc.  These bugs, however, you would never find when creating mocks: Since you implement the mocks yourself, you implement them based on the same (mis-)understanding that you have when writing the code.

Consequently, to find such bugs, you would have to integration-test your code with the real adm-zip anyway, because only then you fill find the flaws in your understanding of the adm-zip module.

Conclusion: Skip unit-testing here and directly go to integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) module to stub the `adm-zip` module.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

async function main() {
  const filePath = 'some file path';
  const outputPath = './dist';
  const zip = new AdmZip(filePath);
  const response = await zip.extractAllTo(outputPath, true);
}

module.exports = main;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('60595390', () => {
  it('should extract all', async () => {
    const admZipInstance = {
      extractAllTo: sinon.stub(),
    };
    const admZipStub = sinon.stub().callsFake(() => admZipInstance);
    const main = proxyquire('./', {
      'adm-zip': admZipStub,
    });
    await main();
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(admZipStub, 'some file path');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(admZipInstance.extractAllTo, './dist', true);
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
  60595390
    ✓ should extract all (2951ms)


  1 passing (3s)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: I am getting error ```Cannot find module './'``` I tried giving it the proper path of my controller as well. I got ```Cannot find module '../../../controllers/test.controller.ts'```

Comment: @prisoner_of_azkaban I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @Shamshiel

I moved the adm specific code to a separate util file and created a new funciton there
```
export async function extractZip(file, outputPath) {
 const zip = new AdmZip(file);
 await zip.extractAllTo(outputPath, true);
}
```
Then it was easier.

Failure:
```
      testStub = sinon.stub(chaincodeUtils, 'extractZip').usingPromise(Promise).rejects({message : 'Error occured while unzip'});
```
Success:

      ```testStub.restore();
      sinon.stub(chaincodeUtils, 'extractZip').callsFake(function test() {
        return '';
      });```